# can't find the command ’celery‘

Tags: celery

I follow the steps on this website [celery docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#first-steps) to learn celery.

When I run the command 'pip3 install celery' and install the celery successfully. 
[picture link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SD7Lv.png)

But when I run the command 'celery worker --help',the return is can't find the command ’celery‘. Anyone can tell me why? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The celery command is under the ~/.local/bin
Add the ~/.local/bin to env variable(/etc/profile) and then the problem will be solved.

Comment: Putting this in the `/etc/profile` specifically helped me

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com) to manage Python, then you need to "reshim" your pip-installed executables, like so:

```
asdf reshim python
```

[More details here from chriserin of hashrocket.](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/ques11vrjs-get-pip-installed-executables-into-the-asdf-path)